# HAProxy 2.4 does not forward HTTP / Hangs

Tags: haproxy, docker-compose

I have a server using docker-compose using the image `haproxy:1.4`. It works fine but I wanted to migrate to a more recent version. But starting with `haproxy:2.4`, haproxy does not work anymore.

This my config (except from the log configuration, this is the exact same config I had with 1.4):

```
global
  maxconn 256
  log stdout format raw local0 debug

defaults
  log global
  option httplog
  mode http
  timeout connect 5000ms
  timeout client 50000ms
  timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
  bind *:80
  default_backend test

backend test
  server test test:80 maxconn 256
```

`test` is a container running a web server.

When I curl, I get nothing:

```
$ curl -vvv 127.0.0.1:80
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
```

Then it just hangs forever (no timeout).

Although I configured the logs, I get no logs from haproxy:

```
$ docker-compose logs haproxy
haproxy_1          | [NOTICE]   (1) : New worker #1 (8) forked
$
```

Note that with `haproxy:2.3` this works. The first version that start failing is 2.4.

Here is the docker-compose config:

```
  haproxy:
    image: "haproxy:2.4"
    ports:
      - 80:80
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=0
    volumes:
      - "/home/user/config/haproxy/:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/"
    restart: always
```

I had to add `net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start` in order to use port 80 but except from this, this is the same configuration as the 1.4 image.

I don't know why the logs do not show up and I don't why it hangs. How to solve or debug this issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Using haproxy 2.4 and your configuration, it all just works, and I see logs as expected.  See e.g. [this test](https://gist.github.com/larsks/df2e17f2fbdf001577163fb4714e07d7).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reproduce. I see you don't need `ip_unprivileged_port_start`, are you on a kernel before 4.11? (see https://hub.docker.com/_/haproxy/ chapter Run the container). Moreover, I don't understand how you can curl port 80 on the proxy as you are not exposing it outside docker. If you are not able to reproduce the problem, then it must be outside of haproxy and its config.

Comment: My environment is running as root, so that wasn't necessary. You don't need to publish ports to access them on a container -- you can interact directly with the container ip address.